# Problems with for loop in C# ADO net code

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, for-loop, ado.net

I have some serous issues with this code. I have the method `GetWeatherItemData` that takes a parameter name and a period as input for getting data from a SQL database and it seems to work fine.

But I want to create a method that can do the same work for multiple parameters, so I created a method named `GetSelectedWeatherItemsData` that takes an array of parameters as input and loops through my first method, but for some reason it will only return data for 1 parameter only, the first in the array of input parameters.

Here is the first method:

```
public CustomDataType GetWeatherItemData(string parameterName, string fromTime, string toTime)
{
        /* This method takes parameter name, start time and end time as input it will then return 
         * all the measurement values and their timestamp as array for the specific parameter           
         */
        CustomDataType getWeatherItemObj = new CustomDataType();           
        List<double> valueList = new List<double>();
        List<string> timeStampList = new List<string>();
        List<int>   parameterIdList = new List<int>();
        List<string> ParameterNameList = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            using (conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))// create and open a connection object
            {
                // 1. create a command object identifying the stored procedure
                 cmd = new SqlCommand("GetWeatherItemData", conn);

                // 2.Let the command object know we will execute a stored procedure
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                // 3. add the 3 parameters to command, so the can be passed to the stored procedure                  
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@WeatherParameterName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value    = parameterName;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@FromTime", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value                = fromTime;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ToTime", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value                  = toTime;

                //open connection
                conn.Open();

                // execute the command
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        valueList.Add((double)reader["MeasurementValue"]);
                        timeStampList.Add(reader["MeasurementDateTime"].ToString());
                        parameterIdList.Add((int)reader["WeatherParameterID"]);                            
                    }
                } 

                //close connection
                reader.Close();

                //changed to arrays to support webservices
                getWeatherItemObj.arrayOfValue          = valueList.ToArray();
                getWeatherItemObj.arrayOfTimestamp      = timeStampList.ToArray();
                getWeatherItemObj.arrayOfParameterID    = parameterIdList.ToArray();                    

                for (counter = 0; counter < getWeatherItemObj.arrayOfValue.Length; counter++)
                {
                    ParameterNameList.Add(GetParameterInfo(parameterName).ParameterName);
                }

                getWeatherItemObj.arrayOfParameterName = ParameterNameList.ToArray();
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connection failed");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }           
        return getWeatherItemObj;
    }
```

Here is the code I have problem with. It takes an array of parameter names, and period as input. But it only returns data for the first element in the input array, as if it does the for loop only once and jumps out.I tested the code inside the for loop by assigning them a fixed number like `parameterName[3]` instead of `parameterName[counter]` and this resulted in that I got data for that element not the first element. So for some reason the for loops does only 1 iteration.

```
public CustomDataType GetSelectedWeatherItemsData(string[] parameterName, string fromTime, string toTime)
{
        CustomDataType tempObj;     
        List<double> valueList          = new List<double>();
        List<string> timeStampList      = new List<string>();
        List<int> paramIdStampList      = new List<int>();
        List<string> ParameterNameList  = new List<string>();

        for (counter = 0; counter < (parameterName.Length); counter++)
        {
            tempObj = GetWeatherItemData(parameterName[counter], fromTime, toTime);
            valueList.AddRange(GetWeatherItemData(parameterName[counter], fromTime, toTime).arrayOfValue);
            timeStampList.AddRange(GetWeatherItemData(parameterName[counter], fromTime, toTime).arrayOfTimestamp);
            //paramIdStampList.AddRange(tempObj.arrayOfParameterID);
            ParameterNameList.AddRange(GetWeatherItemData(parameterName[counter], fromTime, toTime).arrayOfParameterName);
        }

        getSelectedItemsObj                         = new CustomDataType();
        getSelectedItemsObj.arrayOfValue            = valueList.ToArray();
        getSelectedItemsObj.arrayOfTimestamp        = timeStampList.ToArray();
        //getSelectedItemsObj.arrayOfParameterID    = paramIdStampList.ToArray();
        getSelectedItemsObj.arrayOfParameterName    = ParameterNameList.ToArray();

        return getSelectedItemsObj;
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to debug this loop?

Comment: Magic strings should be avoided.

Comment: Yes i tested the loop by setting parameterName[1] and other element numbers, and it returned data for them only

Comment: Shouldn't you use `tempObj` in lines from 2 to 5 of the loop body? Or you are doing one and the same request to the database several times

Comment: sorry i didnt get that where should i move it?

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov is saying that you have assigned `tempObj` in the first line of your loop, but not used it anywhere else. You assign the data to it and then never use it again, making it superfluous.

Comment: You need to do some more debugging: make sure your loop is executing the desired number of times; make sure the desired parameters are being passed in to `GetWeatherItemData` each time; make sure that `GetWeatherItemData` is performing as desired and placing the data you want into the return object.

Answer (score 1):

What seems definitely wrong is the fact you're calling the *simple* web service **four times** inside your loop - why don't you just call it once and then use the results you get back?

Something like:

```
for (counter = 0; counter < (parameterName.Length); counter++)
{
    tempObj = GetWeatherItemData(parameterName[counter], fromTime, toTime);

    valueList.AddRange(tempObj.arrayOfValue);
    timeStampList.AddRange(tempObj.arrayOfTimestamp);
    //paramIdStampList.AddRange(tempObj.arrayOfParameterID);
    ParameterNameList.AddRange(tempObj.arrayOfParameterName);
}
```

Comment: I tried this also, it also only gets data for 1 the first element

Comment: @user1810659 could you explain in greater details, what you mean saying *gets data for 1 the first element*?